# print(target.size()s_history) SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: pytorch, jupyter, mobilenet, siamese-network

```
File "/tmp/ipykernel_15300/319840370.py", line 18
print(target.size()s_history)
^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: As the error said, it is a syntax error. `print(target.size(), s_history)`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

If `target.size()` and `s_history` are two different arguments:

```
print(target.size(), s_history)
```

If `s_history is an attribute of whatever` size()` method returns:

```
print(target.size().s_history)
```